# android+appium+switch of activity in app

Tags: appium

We start off with the launch activity and navigate through the app using appium automation so is there any way to know in what activity of app i am currently in ?
or to know when a particular activity got killed and other got started ?

thanx in advance!

Comment: Hi 
Can you please tell me how to switch from one app to another app at run time using appium

Answer (score 2):

driver.currentActivity(); should return you the current activity